# Maintenance Plan Execute option is greyed out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maintenance-plan

When I go to SQL Server Management Studio -> Management -> Maintenance Plans -> Right click on the maintenance plan that I want to execute but the option is greyed out.

[image]

- I have checked and SQL Server Integration Services is running.
- I can execute other maintenance plans.
- I have even tried modifying this plan without an issue but Execute stays greyed out.
- There is no other instance of the plan running at the moment.
- I have also disconnected from the SQL Server and connected back but that didn't help either.
- SQL Agent is running.

Comment: Is your SQL Agent is running?

Comment: Yes. Agent was running. I restarted my machine and Execute option is not greyed out anymore. I shouldn't have to restart the machine. Anyways, don't know how/why it happened but the issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turns out it was an execution window that was buried. It doesn't show as an "open window" when you look at the taskbar at the SSMS icon, so it's deceptive. ALT-TAB your way through the windows and you should find it.

The open windows was:

[image: the hidden window]

Comment: Pop unders are the devil.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how many hours SO answers has saved me from trivial and confusing stuff like this. Thanks!

Comment: My Lord, thankfully we have stackexachange websites, because I started thinking about reinstalling sql server ;)

Comment: 4 years later, SQL2016, and this is still valid.

Comment: @callisto Happens to me in the most recent build of SSMS17 too (I think this also happens in SSMS18 too... ugh). I appreciate that at least it's not a needlessly blocking modal dialog, but why can't SSMS use a tool window to show task execution status?

Comment: Well, I did not expect to be this answer :-D

Comment: SSMS UI is a long standing abomination. Some popups are unusable with screen scaling. I had to turn my 4K monitor down to 100% and use a magnifying glass to use the dialog!

Answer (score 4):

Just try to restart SQL Management Studio

Comment: It didn't helped. @user35762 provided right solution to this 'issue'

Answer (score 3):

Restarting SSMS worked for me. I had a hidden dialog stuck in the back ground.